# How to do multiple API requests with Android-Async-Http?

Tags: android, api, request, android-async-http

in my app i have to call an API for about 20 times after an the activity starts. There is no posibility to get all the data in one call.

At the moment im using Android-Async-Http for only one call like this and it works well:

```
client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(DetailsActivity.this, url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
//working with the data
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
```

But what is the best way to do multiple calls against an API?

Ok, this is the way im doing it now:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

         URL url;
         BufferedReader reader = null;
         String s = "";
         try {
             url = new URL(params[0]);
             URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
             reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
             String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 s = s + line;
             }
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }  catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
             if (reader != null) {
                 try {
                     reader.close();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }
         Log.i(null, "response: " + s);
         return s;
     }
```

this allows me to start a lot of requests at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: I suggest you use Retrofit instead of Asystask to call multi request in short time. Here is example : http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/

Comment: Do you need to download all this within an Activity? And do you need to make these calls every time Activity gets started? Maybe using some Service/SyncAdapter implementation for pre-fetching + storing results within a database would work?

Comment: I added my solution in the question!  Like this I am able to do a lot of requests at the same time. What are the advantages of Retrofit against my solution? Is it possible in Retrofit to just get the String back? Im still using gson to parse my jsons to class. Maybe I should do all requests after the application is started up. What is the fastest way to save large jsons? I did take a look at SQLite but this is a lot of typing :( Is there a better way with less typing but as fast as SQLite? Is there a complete example for a SyncAdapter?